# Solution of an equation by algebraic method

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is algebraic method solution of the following equation:

$$\log_\sqrt{5}x=(\sqrt5)^x$$

Comment: What does the left-hand side of that even mean? There's no argument to the logarithm!

Comment: Do you mean $\log_x \sqrt{5} = (\sqrt{5})^x$?

Comment: @Bacon:Logarithm base is $\sqrt5$

Comment: @Bacon: Ok thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @Bacon supposed, let us admit that you are looking for the zero of function $$f(x)=\log_x (\sqrt{5}) - (\sqrt{5})^x$$ I do not think that this  transcendental  equation could show explicit solution even using special functions.

So, numerical methods should be required. Looking at the plot of the function, you probably noticed that the solution is around $x_0=1.5$. So, start iterating using Newton method which will update the guess according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ The iterates would be$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.50000 \\
 1 & 1.27175 \\
 2 & 1.31458 \\
 3 & 1.32047 \\
 4 & 1.32056  
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Now, if the equation you need to solve is 
$$g(x)=\log_{\sqrt{5}}(x) - (\sqrt{5})^x$$
it does not show any solution in the real domain. Plotting it, you would see a maximum close to $x=0.86$ and, at this point, the function value is negative.